# how can I speed up this look up and sum function in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

EDIT: There were lots of problems in my first example so I am reworking them here. This is primarily to direct credit towards the original responder who cut my process time by a factor of about 180 even with my poor example. This question was frozen for being unclear, or not general enough, but I think it has value as data.table can do amazing things with the right syntax, but that syntax can be elusive even with the available vignettes. From my own experience, having more examples of how data.table can be used will be helpful. Particularly for those of us who got our start in Excel the VLOOKUP like behavior here fills a gap that is not always easy to find.

The specific things that happen in this example that may be of general interest are:

1. looking up values in one data.table in another data.table
2. passing variables by name and by reference
3. apply like behavior in data.table

Original question with modified (limited rows) example:

I am looking for help in the arcane world of data.table, passing functions, and fast use of lookups across multiple tables. I have a larger function that, when I profile it, seems to spend all of its time in this one area doing some fairly straightforward lookup and sum actions. I am not adept enough at profiling to figure out exactly which subareas of the call are causing the problem but my guess is that I am unintentionally doing something computationally expensive that I don't need to do. Data.table syntax is still a complete mystery to me, so I am seeking help here to speed this process up.

Small worked example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(seed = 911)
##Other parts of the analysis generate all of these data.tables
#A data table containing id values (the real version has other things too)
whoamI<-data.table(id=1:5)
#The result of another calculation it tells me how many neighbors I will be interested in
#the real version has many more columns in it.
howmanyneighbors<-data.table(id=1:5,toCount=round(runif(5,min=1,max=3),0))
#Who the first three neighbors are for each id
#real version has a hundreds of neighbors
myneighborsare<-data.table(id=1:5,matrix(1:5,ncol=3,nrow=5,byrow = TRUE))
colnames(myneighborsare)<-c("id","N1","N2","N3")
#How many of each group live at each location?
groupPops<-data.table(id=1:5,matrix(floor(runif(25,min=0,max=10)),ncol=5,nrow=5))
colnames(groupPops)<-c("id","ape","bat","cat","dog","eel")

whoamI
howmanyneighbors
myneighborsare
groupPops

> whoamI
   id
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4:  4
5:  5
> howmanyneighbors
   id toCount
1:  1       2
2:  2       1
3:  3       3
4:  4       3
5:  5       2
> myneighborsare
   id N1 N2 N3
1:  1  1  2  3
2:  2  4  5  1
3:  3  2  3  4
4:  4  5  1  2
5:  5  3  4  5
> groupPops
   id ape bat cat dog eel
1:  1   9   8   6   8   1
2:  2   9   8   0   9   8
3:  3   6   1   9   1   2
4:  4   6   1   9   0   3
5:  5   6   2   2   2   5
##At any given time I will only want the group populations for some of the groups
#I will always want 'ape' but other groups will vary. Here I have picked two
#I retain this because passing the column names by variable along with the pass of 'ape' was tricky
#and I don't want to lose that syntax in any new answer
animals<-c("bat","eel")
i<-2 #similarly, howmanyneighbors has many more columns in it and I need to pass a reference to one of them which I call i here


##Functions I will call on the above data
#Get the ids of my neighbors from myneighborsare. The number of ids returned will vary based on value in howmanyneighbors
getIDs<-function(a){myneighborsare[id==a,2:(as.numeric(howmanyneighbors[id==a,..i])+1)]} #so many coding fails here it pains me to put this in public view
#Sum the populations of my neighbors for groups I am interested in.
sumVals<-function(b){colSums(groupPops[id%in%b,c("ape",..animals)])} #cringe
#Wrap the first two together and put them into a format that works well with being returned as a row in a data.table
doBoth<-function(a){
  ro.ws<-getIDs(a)
  su.ms<-sumVals(ro.ws)
  answer<-lapply(split(su.ms,names(su.ms)),unname) #not too worried about this as it just mimics some things that happen in the original code at little time cost
  return(answer)
}

#Run the above function on my data
result<-data.table(whoamI)
result[,doBoth(id),by=id]

   id ape bat eel
1:  1  18  16   9
2:  2   6   1   3
3:  3  21  10  13
4:  4  24  18  14
5:  5  12   2   5
```

Comment: can you explain what you are looking for given "ape", `animals` and `i`? got a feeling that if u convert everything into a long format, you can do away with all these functions

Comment: Would be great if you made clear what are the inputs and how the output should look like and perhaps you can shorten your data (just adds to confusion you have more data than necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves a reshape and non-equi join.

```
library(data.table)

# reshape to long and add a grouping ID for a non-equi join later
molten_neighbors <- melt(myneighborsare, id.vars = 'id')[, grp_id := .GRP, by = variable]

#regular join by id
whoamI[howmanyneighbors,
       on = .(id)
#non-equi join - replaces getIDs(a)     
       ][molten_neighbors,
         on = .(id, toCount >= grp_id),
         nomatch = 0L
#regular join - next steps replace sumVals(ro.ws)        
         ][groupPops[, c('id','ape', ..animals)],
           on = .(value = id),
           .(id, ape, bat, eel),
           nomatch = 0L,

           ][,
             lapply(.SD, sum),
             keyby = id 
             ]
```

I highly recommend simplifying future questions. Using 10 rows allows you to post the tables within your question. As is, it was somewhat difficult to follow.

Comment: Strong work given my poor question. My run time dropped from 4 hours to 4 minutes with these changes. I knew this should be possible, but getting my head around data.table is still hard even after a couple of years of trying. Thanks for persevering.